# Using Java nio Files,Rename Directory but if already exists move the files to existing Directory

Tags: java, java-7

I want to rename Dir "Dir1" to "Dir2".

But if "Dir2" exits then i want to move "Dir1" files to "Dir2". 
C:\Artwork\Dir1
C:\Artwork\Dir2
For Rename

```
Files.move(path, path.resolveSibling("NewName"))); //Worked Ok
```

For Dir already present i tried

```
Path source = Paths.get("C:\\Artwork\\Dir1");
Path newDir = Paths.get("C:\\Artwork\\Dir2");
Files.move(source, newDir,StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE); //Throwed AccessDeniedException
Files.move(source, newDir,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING); //Throwed DirectoryNotEmptyException
```

Comment: It sounds like there's a problem in the "dir already present" case? If something is not working, please tell us about it.

Comment: Files.move(source, newDir,StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Artwork\Dir1 -> C:\Artwork\Dir2
Files.move(source, newDir,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've written some utility methods to copy directories using the NIO File API (the library is Open Source):

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.3</version>  
</dependency>
```

Tutorial:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/tutorial/nio-file/index.html

API:
[CopyFileVisitor.copy](http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-core/org/softsmithy/lib/nio/file/CopyFileVisitor.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path%29)

Answer (score 1):

If  Dir2 is not exist then  use `Dir2.mkdir();`  to Create a Directory. If it is already exixt then `moveDirectory(File Dir1, File Dir2);`
 we can move whole directory

Comment: Thanks Chakri,I can do that but i want to use Java 7 nio Files.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 1.7 there is java.nio.file.Files which offers operations to work with files and directories. Especially the move, copy and walkFileTree functions.